# How to subset a big dataset with pandas or sklearn to shorten run time for model training?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, sklearn-pandas

This is a general question but I attached a real data set to illustrate idea. When I trained a model on a very large data set, it took me hours to finished(logistic regression, macbook air, CPU:1.4 GHz Intel Core i5 8G RAM). Is there a way to divide/ shard the training data per se, so we can more efficiently compute the model performance in `sklearn` or `python`?

The dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_covtype
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cov.data.shape  #(581012 rows, 54 features)
cov = fetch_covtype()
cov_data = pd.DataFrame(cov.data)
cov_target = pd.DataFrame(cov.target)
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a subset to run through for development you can just insert a line early on that's `cov = cov[:5000]`

If you're past that and want to evaluate your model's performance, I suggest sklearn [test_train_split](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)